# Serialize type to an arbitrary string

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I've declared a struct TaxpayerIdentificationNumber, that contains private long and represents 13 digits.
I want to be able to serialize it into a mere string, that contains that private number (padded with zeros in front, but never mind it).

For example, we have DateTime, that serializes to "2020-01-01T00.00.01" and not to "{'ticks': 34546 }". I want that special treatment for my types too. And deserialization from a simple string as well.

I've explored ISerialized and its associated method and constructor, but didn't eventually understand, how to just define the method, which will form the final string I want.

Comment: You can add methods to that type that serialize and deserialize it, but I don't think you can enforce all serializers to use them.

Comment: You are targeting Json not "any" type of serialization?

Comment: Can you clarify what serializer you are trying to use here? it *looks* like you're using JSON - is that right? if so: what serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're doing JSON serialization; so, something like this, assuming you're using Newtonsoft.Json?

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

var obj = new HazFoo { Value = new("whatever") };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj); // {"Value":"whatever"}
Console.WriteLine(json);
var clone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HazFoo>(json);
Console.WriteLine(clone.Value.TaxpayerIdentificationNumber); // whatever

class HazFoo
{
    public Foo Value { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(FooConverter))]
readonly struct Foo : IEquatable<Foo>
{
    public string TaxpayerIdentificationNumber { get; }

    public Foo(string id) => TaxpayerIdentificationNumber = id;

    private sealed class FooConverter : JsonConverter<Foo>
    {
        public override Foo ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Foo existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
            => new Foo((string)reader.Value);

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Foo value, JsonSerializer serializer)
            => writer.WriteValue(value.TaxpayerIdentificationNumber);
    }

    // these have nothing to do with serialization, but are good practice
    // for value-types, to avoid unnecessary boxing
    public override bool Equals([NotNullWhen(true)] object obj)
        => obj is Foo other && Equals(other);
    public override int GetHashCode()
        => TaxpayerIdentificationNumber?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    public override string ToString()
        => TaxpayerIdentificationNumber;
    public bool Equals(Foo other)
        => TaxpayerIdentificationNumber == other.TaxpayerIdentificationNumber;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I use Newtonsoft.Json, but I actually wanted the solution to be framework-agnostic. The result is fine, though - exactly what I wanted. I'll mark it as the solution if nothing universal appears. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the ISerializable interface and provide your own implementation for the GetObjectData method. This method is called during serialization and lets you write the data of your object to a SerializationInfo object, which is used to create a serialized representation of the object.

```
[Serializable]
public struct TaxpayerIdentificationNumber : ISerializable
{
    private long _number;

    public TaxpayerIdentificationNumber(long number)
    {
        _number = number;
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        string serialized = _number.ToString().PadLeft(13, '0');
        info.AddValue("serialized", serialized);
    }

    // Other methods and properties of your struct...

}
```

The example first converts the private _number field to a string and pad it with zeros to a length of 13. We then add this serialized string to the SerializationInfo object with a key of "serialized". During deserialization, we can then retrieve this serialized string and use it to reconstruct our object.

You can add a constructor that takes a SerializationInfo object and retrieve the serialized string from it. Like the below

```
[Serializable]
public struct TaxpayerIdentificationNumber : ISerializable
{
    private long _number;

    public TaxpayerIdentificationNumber(long number)
    {
        _number = number;
    }

    public TaxpayerIdentificationNumber(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        string serialized = (string)info.GetValue("serialized", typeof(string));
        _number = long.Parse(serialized);
    }

    // Other methods and properties of your struct...

}
```

In the example above we retrieve the serialized string from the SerializationInfo object with a key of "serialized". Finally, we parse this string back into a long and assign it to the private _number field.

Comment: I doubt that ISerializable has anything to do with what OP is actually trying to do here

Comment: It's not my goal. I don't want the serialized object to contain anything but the padded number value, so it just is "1234554321123".